# Connecting to MySQL from other machines

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2003, database-connection

I have MySQL installed on a Windows 2003 server on our domain.  I cannot connect to it from other machines on the domain.  I open up the MySQL Administrator panel and try to change the server name from localhost to the machine name it does not recognize it.  I have tried fully qualifying the name also.  Any ideas what I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to connect to the database using the default root userid.  I created a new user and gave this user read permission to the needed tables.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of error, a total inability to connect?  Windows Firewall is the first place I'd look, to make sure port 3306 is open.

Answer (score 1):

have you double checked permissions on the databases using something like

`grant all priviliges on 'database'.'*' to 'username'@'remote_machine_ip' identified by 'password';`

Like Sukasa mentioned, also double check any firewalls you may have configured

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in the my.cnf file and look for the `bind-address` setting and the `skip-networking` setting. You want the latter removed or commented out and the former to be the machine's IP address. Restart MySQL after you make changes.

A number of MySQL install packages defaulted to a local socket only install, which is helpful for security but considerably impairs network connectivity. :-)

Comment: Here is what I found in my.cnf 
#skip-networking
server-id = 1

Cannot find a bind-address setting.  What should I change?

Comment: Okay, if bind-address is absent it should be listening on all addresses. I'd be checking MySQL permissions - see Dan Klassen's answer.